# How to create dynamic form elements using cloneNode

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an interactive resume template using javascript and html and have managed to use `cloneNode` to duplicate **work history** blocks (see attached screenshot)

[image]

The problem(s) I am having is that clicking on the **add list item** button in the cloned/duplicated **work history** block at the bottom, creates a `<li>` item in the 1st/cloned element.

The objective is to be able to add or delete ````` list elements within a specific **work history** block and to also be able to add/remove entire **work history** sections. Currently it deletes from the top down, which is also an issue.

Thanks for any pointers in advance.

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>





<div id="test">

    <div id="node">
    
    <div class="work_history">

    <div class="row">
    
    <strong>
    <input type="text" name="company" value="ACME Company">
    </strong>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
    
    <input type="text" name="position" value="Cheese Taster">
    
    </div>
    
    <input type="text" name="start" value="1/2019">    
    <input type="text" name="end" value="2/2020"> 

    <ul id="list">    
        <li>    
            <textarea id="task" name="task" rows="4" cols="50">Did some things. Tasted cheese.</textarea>
        </li>
        
        <button onclick="addTask()">Add List Item</button> 
        <button onclick="RemoveTask()">Delete List Item</button>
        
    </ul>
    
    <button onclick="addWork()">Add Work</button> 
    <button onclick="removeWork()">Remove Work</button>
    
</div>
</div>
</div>





<script>
function addWork() {

    
    var div = document.getElementById("node");
    var cln = div.cloneNode(true);    
    //cln.setAttribute( 'id', 'newId');
    document.getElementById("test").appendChild(cln); 
   
    }

function removeWork(){

    var last = document.getElementById("test");
    // want to delete the last added work history not first
    last.removeChild(last.childNodes[0]);  
}

function addTask(){

    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    var task = document.getElementById("task");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute('id',task.value);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

function removeTask(){

    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    var task = document.getElementById("task");
    var item = document.getElementById(task.value);
    ul.removeChild(item);
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use `e.currentTarget` instead of `document.getElementById`, otherwise you're only referring to the first instance of it:

```js
function addWork(e) {
  const div = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
  const cln = div.cloneNode(true);

  document.getElementById("test").appendChild(cln);
}

function removeWork(e) {
  const last = e.currentTarget.parentElement;

  last.parentElement.removeChild(last);
}

function addTask(e) {
  const ul = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
  let task = ul.children[0].childNodes[1].value;
  let li = document.createElement("li");

  // Replace paragraph breaks
  task = task.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ");

  li.innerText = task;

  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function removeTask(e) {
  const ul = e.currentTarget.parentNode;

  ul.removeChild(ul.lastChild);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="test">
    <div id="node">
      <div class="work_history">
        <div class="row">
          <strong>
              <input type="text" name="company" value="ACME Company">
            </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <input type="text" name="position" value="Cheese Taster">
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="start" value="1/2019">
        <input type="text" name="end" value="2/2020">
        <ul id="list">
          <li>
            <textarea name="task" rows="4" cols="50">Did some things. Tasted cheese.</textarea>
          </li>
          <button onclick="addTask(event)">Add List Item</button>
          <button onclick="removeTask(event)">Delete List Item</button>
        </ul>
        <button onclick="addWork(event)">Add Work</button>
        <button onclick="removeWork(event)">Remove Work</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This allows you to refer to the specific element where the click event occurred and add/remove any elements that are relative within the DOM.

As a side note, it's best practice to have unique `id` attributes, adding the same `id` to multiple elements goes against that.

Comment: thanks for this. Assigning new ids to the elements dynamically is tricky. Perhaps creating a counter that increments/decrements for work/task blocks that can be appended to the id of each element work?

Answer (score -1):

```js
        var add_button = $(".add_form_field");
        var wrapper = $(".container1");
        var max_fields = 9;
  var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append(
                `  <div class="email">
              <label for="">Year</label>
              <input type="text" name="eduYear${x}">
              <label for="">Title Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="eduTitle${x}">
              <label for="">Institution/School Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="eduPlace${x}">
              <label for="">Details</label>
              <input type="text" name="eduNotes${x}"> <br><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a><hr></div>`
            ); //add input box
        }
    });
  
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent("div").remove();
        x--;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
            <h2>Educations</h2>
            <button type="button" class="add_form_field">Add Education &nbsp;
              <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span>
            </button>
            <div class="email">
              <label for="">Year</label>
              <input type="number" name="eduYear1">
              <label for="">Title Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="eduTitle1">
              <label for="">Institution/School Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="eduPlace1">
              <label for="">Details</label>
              <input type="text" name="eduNotes1">

            </div>
```

you can try this to create dynamic form